# itextsharp multipage pdf form

Tags: c#, itext

I've got a pdf template and i want to generate for every records in database.
I've find this but it works only on phisical file. How to make this work only in memory?
I tried to use memorystream but i can't read this with PdfReader

```
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uniqueidstr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string file = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/PrimaVisita.pdf");

        string MasterPdfFile = Server.MapPath("./MstrCopyFile" + uniqueidstr + ".pdf").ToString();

        PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(new FileStream(MasterPdfFile, FileMode.CreateNew));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PdfReader tmpReader = new PdfReader(file);
            string tmpfilepath = Server.MapPath("./tmpFile" + uniqueidstr + i.ToString() + ".pdf").ToString();

            FileStream tmpOutFileStream = new FileStream(tmpfilepath, FileMode.CreateNew);
            PdfStamper tmpOutStamper = new PdfStamper(tmpReader, tmpOutFileStream);
            AcroFields fields = tmpOutStamper.AcroFields;
            fields.SetField("Cognome", "pippo" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Nome", "pluto" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("DatiNascita", "paperino" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Residenza", "topolino" + i.ToString());

            tmpOutStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            tmpOutStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            tmpOutStamper.Close();
            tmpOutFileStream.Close();

            PdfReader nwPgReader = new PdfReader(tmpfilepath);

            copy.AddDocument(nwPgReader);
        }

        copy.Close();
    }
}
```

the error is "PDF header signature not found."
here is the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uniqueidstr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string file = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/PrimaVisita.pdf");

        MemoryStream masterStream = new MemoryStream();
        //string MasterPdfFile = Server.MapPath("./MstrCopyFile" + uniqueidstr + ".pdf").ToString();

        PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(masterStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PdfReader tmpReader = new PdfReader(file);
            string tmpfilepath = Server.MapPath("./tmpFile" + uniqueidstr + i.ToString() + ".pdf").ToString();
            MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();

            //FileStream tmpOutFileStream = new FileStream(tmpfilepath, FileMode.CreateNew);
            PdfStamper tmpOutStamper = new PdfStamper(tmpReader, tmpStream);
            AcroFields fields = tmpOutStamper.AcroFields;
            fields.SetField("Cognome", "pippo" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Nome", "pluto" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("DatiNascita", "paperino" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Residenza", "topolino" + i.ToString());

            tmpOutStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            tmpOutStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            tmpOutStamper.Close();
            //tmpOutFileStream.Close();

            PdfReader nwPgReader = new PdfReader(tmpStream);

            copy.AddDocument(nwPgReader);
        }

        copy.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You say *I tried to use memorystream but i can't read this with PdfReader* --- what happened when you tried?

Comment: tanks for the reply there was an error about pdf header

Comment: That sounds like the `MemoryStream` had an incorrect position for reading. Please add the code you used then to your question.

Comment: Try rewinding the `MemoryStream`, `tmpStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: i've also tryed this but nothing new happened

Comment: Also, don't close your MemoryStream, `tmpOutStamper.Close();`

Comment: He already set close stream to false...

Answer (score 1):

I solved by converting memorystream in byte array and now it works.

tanks for your support

Bruno

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uniqueidstr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string file = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/PrimaVisita.pdf");

        MemoryStream masterStream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(masterStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PdfReader tmpReader = new PdfReader(file);
            MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
            tmpStream.Position = 0;

            PdfStamper tmpOutStamper = new PdfStamper(tmpReader, tmpStream);
            AcroFields fields = tmpOutStamper.AcroFields;
            fields.SetField("Cognome", "pippo" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Nome", "pluto" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("DatiNascita", "paperino" + i.ToString());
            fields.SetField("Residenza", "topolino" + i.ToString());

            tmpOutStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            tmpOutStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            tmpOutStamper.Close();
            byte[] buf = tmpStream.ToArray();

            PdfReader nwPgReader = new PdfReader(buf);

            copy.AddDocument(nwPgReader);
        }

        copy.Close();


}
```